# QGIS Legend Settings

Tags: qgis, legend

QGIS 3.32 (but always been an issue). Is there any control over the default setting of Legend Items? By default the "Auto Update" is checked ON, and the "Only show items inside linked maps" is checked OFF.
If both these were the opposite option then it wouldn't take so long to load when you add a Legend to a map layout, and you'd only get the items in the map rather than every layer.
Be great if there was a way of choosing some of the default settings for Legends.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it with python, the following script will turn it off for all layouts in the project:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()                                  
manager = project.layoutManager()
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
for layout in layouts_list:
    legends = [i for i in layout.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemLegend)]
    for legend in legends:
        legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
        legend.refresh()
    layout.refresh()
```

you can put this script in the open_project function in the project properties:

[image]